# Как сделать чтобы кнопка нажималась при прикосновении? unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Практикуюсь в Unity и на данный момент хочу создать пианино.

Как сделать, чтобы созданные (UI - buttons) кнопки срабатывали после прикосновения пальца, то есть, можно было водить по набору кнопок не отпуская пальца от экрана и при этом они воспроизводили заданный мною скрипт?

На данный момент, чтобы кнопка воспроизвела мой скрипт, **нужно отпустить** палец именно в её зоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете рассмотреть альтернативный метод, как бы велосипед, достаточно в ваш скрипт добавить использование интерфейса и всё.

```
public class Keys: MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler {

    public AudioClip Sound;
    public AudioSource source; // ну или сразу запихите этот аудиоСурс в поле, дабы не вызывать GetComponent.
    public Image image; // можете такое добавить, если хотите регулировать цвет самостоятельно, без использования компонента Button
    void Start(){
        source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){
        source.PlayOneShot(Sound);
        image.color = Color.yellow;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){ // это опционально
        image.color = Color.white;
    }

}
```

Рекомендую вам не использоваться *AddComponent* так как это трудоёмкий процесс добавления компонента на объект.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть в сторону реализации интерфейсов [Event System](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/EventSystem.html). В вашем случае это может быть [IPointerEnterHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html).

Т.е. классу задаётся наследование от данного интерфейса, пишется реализация этого метода, а сам класс вешается на объект-клавишу.

Когда курсор будет входить в область кнопки - у класса будет вызываться этот метод. Внутри метода вы можете проверить зажата ли сейчас кнопка мыши и если зажата - произвести действие.

Answer (score 0):

Унаследоваться от `Button` и реализовать `OnPointerDown`:

```
public class MyBestButton : Button {
    [...]

    public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData) {
        base.OnPointerDown(eventData);

        if (eventData.button != PointerEventData.InputButton.Left) return;

        // здесь делаем всякое разное       
    }
}
```

Ну или через `AddComponent` навесить триггер, если не хотите классов создавать:

```
EventTrigger trigger = myButton.gameObject.AddComponent<EventTrigger>();
var pointerDown = new EventTrigger.Entry();
pointerDown.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
pointerDown.callback.AddListener(delegate(BaseEventData arg0) { 
    // тут делаем всякое разное
});
trigger.triggers.Add(pointerDown);
```

Comment: Не совсем понял как это работает. 
Вот у меня есть такая программа [ссылка](https://imgur.com/a/6bZWTWw)
На кнопках расположен скрипт "Keys" с данным кодом: [ссылка](https://imgur.com/a/tyycBNs)
Как мне реализовать данный EventTrigger или OnPointerDown учитывая мой код?